# Compare symbol C++

Tags: c++, compare

I am trying to take an argument in the form of `>` in Linux.
I am trying to solve my problem ,like this :

```
std::string big(">");

if (argv[3]==big) {....}
```

But It doesn't work like this.

But It works like this:

```
std::string big("M");

if (argv[3]==big) {....}
```

I guess, I need to get `ASCII CODE` of my char and compare with `argv[3]`. But `argv[3]` it is type of a `char` , I connot compare `int` and `char`.
Can you help me?

Comment: It works fine, there is no need for any ASCII code weirdness. The problem is probably that the shell/terminal/command line thing you are using is treating `>` as a special character and you need to write `">"` or `\>` instead.

Comment: And `argv[3]` is `char*`.

Comment: @nwp Sorry,But can I do it like `>` and sont use anything else?

Comment: @LogicStuff Since `big` is a `std::string` that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Most shells (including the Windows CMD) handles symbols like `<`, `>` and `|` in a special way. `<` is input redirection, `>` is output redirection, and `|` is piping output from one process to the input of another.

Therefore you will never be able to get those symbols as arguments to your process, the command-line environment will use them and will not pass them on to your program.

Unix shells with background job support also adds `&` to the mix.

Comment: It is so sad;( Thanks for answer!